# Unable to get custom workflow condition to work

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a custom workflow condition following the official msdn documentation found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161068%28v=office.12%29.aspx). I think I did everything correct (obviously not) and the following error is displayed within SharePoint Designer 2010 when I am going into the workflow section:

> The list of workflow actions on the server references an assembly that does not exist.     Some actions will not be available. The assembly strong name is **WorkflowConditions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culsture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a451c5304570ce87**. Contact your server administrator for more information.

To my understanding this means that the assembly referenced in the web.config does not exist. So i checked the global assembly cache (GAC) and indeed within `C:\Windows\assembly\` i am unable to find the assembly `WorkflowConditions`.

However, i did install that assembly (the way i understand it) using `gacutil.exe`

```
gacutil.exe /i WorkflowConditions.dll
Message returned: Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

Checking `gacutil.exe /l` i can get a list of all assemblies currently stored (as far as I do understand it), and the penultimate entry is:

```
WorkflowConditions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a451c5304570ce87, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

So i really do not understand why this thing isn't working. And it's weird that gacutil.exe tells me my assembly is stored in the cache, but i can not see it inside the folder!?

I can't really tell what more information you guys might need, so here is what i can come up with ;)

**CustomConditions.Actions**
Identical to the one in the link above with the following Condition:

```
<Condition Name="Project Status Needs Updating"
  FunctionName="StatusNeedsUpdating"
  ClassName="WorkflowConditions.CustomConditions"
  Assembly="WorkflowConditions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a451c5304570ce87"
  AppliesTo="all"
  UsesCurrentItem="true">
```

As asked in the documentation i copied the `CustomConditions.Actions`-File into the Sharepoint Workflows Folder - in my case (since i am not sure about the number) i copied this to the following locations:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1031\Workflow\CustomConditions.Actions
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow\CustomConditions.Actions
```

**Web.Config Entry**

```
<authorizedTypes>
  .....
  <authorizedType Assembly="WorkflowConditions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a451c5304570ce87" Namespace="WorkflowConditions" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
</authorizedTypes>
```

I redid everything from scratch and i always get stuck at this point. What can i possibly continue to check to get this running? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/d939cbb9-a48d-4d39-9717-ff8586af20db

thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly that really doesn't help - there is no given solution. I have written down everything that i could find out on my own and apart from the additional entry of gacutil `, processorArchitecture=MSIL` there is not a single difference, neither in the `web.config` nor in the `.actions`. The Problem though appears to be the same, i am unable to really deploy that `.dll`

Comment: The Problem is: `gacutil /i bla.dll` "Assembly successfully added to the cache" and then `gacutil /u bla.dll` returns "No assemblies found matching: bla.dll" I just do not understand why the assembly does not get installed properly. Drag and Drop the DLL into assembly folder doesn't work, gacutil doesn't work - what else can i try?

Comment: if the dll's aren't showing you can first try Build -> Build Solution.

Comment: The solution itself has been built and i got my `.dll` however i am unable to properly 'install' this file into the GAC so that sharepoint is able to call it. I've pointed out all my steps above and i really can't find an error.

Comment: have you tried using powershell? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-install-or-uninstall-dll-in-gac-using-powershell/

Comment: Thanks for the tip using PS. Other than the normal command prompt PS gave me an error saying that the runtime environment used to create the .dll is never than the currently running runtime. So that's why it doesn't get added to the GAC. Finally a point where i can start to fix things! ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use gacutil /u bla

The .dll is only required on installation

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you compiled in .NET 3.5 mode for a SharePoint 2010 environment. If you compile in .NET 4.0 mode you can see it in the 4.0 GAC under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL rather than the 2.0 GAC at C:\Windows\assembly\
2. If your assembly has a depenancy that isn't GAC'd then SPD will report that it can't find the assembly it has a reference for rather than the dependency which could be causing your issue.